# What am I missing in this word chain validator? (4clojure)

Tags: clojure

I'm working my way through the 4clojure problem set, and finding myself stuck on the 82nd problem which deals with [word chains](http://www.4clojure.com/problem/82). Could really use another set of eyes on this - I'm quoting most of the problem here, but my question is about one of the chains listed as an invalid one.

> A word chain consists of a set of words ordered so that each word differs by only one letter from the words directly before and after it. The one letter difference can be either an insertion, a deletion, or a substitution. Here is an example word chain:

```
cat -> cot -> coat -> oat -> hat -> hot -> hog -> dog
```

> Write a function which takes a sequence of words, and returns true if they can be arranged into one continous word chain, and false if they cannot.

I wrote a function which seems to validate all the options correctly except the third:

```
#{"to" "top" "stop" "tops" "toss"}
```

This is listed as an invalid word chain, but my program validates as correct. I can also construct the chain myself:

```
to -> top -> stop -> toss -> tops
```

What am I missing? I'm trying to make sense of other people's answers, but how is this not a valid chain to begin with? (I'm happy to post my solution, but my question is mainly regarding the validity of this chain.) Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please post your code instead of writing "I wrote a function" next time. Also, sets (`#{}`) are not ordered collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving from "stop" to "toss" requires more than a single change.
It can't be an insertion or a deletion, since both words are of the same length, and so it must be a substitution.

But turning "stop" into "toss" requires no less than 4 substitutions.
That makes the entire chain invalid.

Comment: Ah I didn't realize the order mattered. That's very helpful, thank you.